# Adding dashed line with layer_lines in ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

this is quite simple but I was not able to find a solution. How can I make a line in layers_lines dashed in ggvis. I'm dealing with a custom type of linear regression and I provide this toy example for my problem:

```
library(ggvis)
W=seq(0,10,0.1)
data=data.frame(fit=3+2*W,upper=4+2*W,lower=2+2*W)
base <- data %>% ggvis(x= ~fit,y= ~W)%>%layer_lines() %>%
layer_lines(x= ~lower,y= ~W)%>%layer_lines(x= ~upper,y= ~W)
```

This produces this image:
[image]

I want the upper and the lower lines to be dashed. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It definitely helps to brush up on Vega to use ggvis. You need to use the `strokeDash` property.

```
library(ggvis)

W <- seq(0, 10, 0.1)

data <- data.frame(fit=3+2*W, upper=4+2*W, lower=2+2*W)

data %>% 
  ggvis(x= ~fit, y= ~W) %>% 
  layer_lines() %>%
  layer_lines(x= ~lower, y= ~W, strokeDash:=6) %>% 
  layer_lines(x= ~upper, y= ~W, strokeDash:=6) -> base

base
```

[image]

Comment: can you add a legend for the solid and the dashed lines? Unlike fill or stroke it does not put that up automatically...

Comment: super gd question. i haven't touched ggvis in a while as it's been kinda of in abandonware mode.

Comment: oh, is it? What do you recommend to go with?? Need it for web use /w shiny, particularly the export stuff seemed nice to me.

Comment: it is, but Hadley (et al) haven't touched it in a while and seem to have no immediate plans to. Perhaps one of the many htmlwidgets would work?

Comment: briefly talked to winston chang on twitter: they have plans to address ggvis at the end of 2016. could be quite an overhaul from what I understand. sounded honest as well as promising :)

Comment: oh Winston is a super great RStudio dev. Just be careful since they declared 2016 would be The Year of ggvis then got distracted :-)